# C# Passed state object to Task gets changed

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I'm fighting with this for days, I hope You can push me in the right direction.

This is a recursive threading algorithm which parses a resource in a thread looking for links to other resources storing them in a `ConcurrentBag` for future TakeOuts. Threads creation is limited by an array with configurable size to preserve resources.

I have a `private static ConcurrentBag<string>` which gets filled by many threads. These are `Tasks` that are stored in `private static Task[]` with configurable size (app preferences).
There is a loop in `Main` that's doing `TryTake()` into local `string url` variable. When successfull it loops the `Task[]` trying to find empty slot creating new `Task` passing state object `url` and storing it in `Task[]` like this:

```
TaskArray[x] = new Task(FindLinks, url, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
```

The `FindLinks` is declared as

```
private static readonly Action<object> FindLinks = input => { ... }
```

In the main `Task[]` loop I am setting `url` to `null` before next `TryTake(out url)`.

What is my problem here is the state object `input` that is passed from `url` in the main loop becomes `null` inside the Task lambda function. I've read almost all MSDN articles about TPL and can't figure this one out :(

How can I pass a variable (string) to the `Task` safely without closure (or whatever it is happening).

Any other ideas about improving this algorithm are welcome too.

Thanks.

Edit:
I have solved the problem by reordering statements and slightly rewriting the code in the main loop. No more assigning null to the variable. I suspect it was caused by compiler's statement reordering or preemption. Here is what it looks like now causing no more troubles:

```
string url;
if (CollectedLinks.TryTake(out url))
{
  var queued = false;
  while (!queued)
  {
    // Loops thru the array looking for empty slot (null)
    for (byte i = 0; i < TaskArray.Length; i++)
    {
      if (TaskArray[i] == null)
      {
        TaskArray[i] = new Task(FindLinks, url, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
        TaskArray[i].Start(TaskScheduler.Current);
        queued = true; break;
      }
    }

    if (!queued)
    {
      // Loop and clean the array
      for (var i = 0; i < TaskArray.Length; i++)
      {
        if (TaskArray[i] == null)
          continue;
        if (TaskArray[i].Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion || TaskArray[i].Status == TaskStatus.Canceled || TaskArray[i].Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
        {
          TaskArray[i].Wait(0);
          TaskArray[i] = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've *described* lots of code, but it would be a lot clearer if you could actually *show* the code. It's quite hard to follow what's going on. In particular, the answer could very easily depend on whether you're capturing any variables.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, the code is so complex and refactored that it will take me some time to gather all the necessary bits and filter out the rest and it will probably take you the same time to link it together in your mind. However, I'll do my best ASAP.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, as it seems you have, you should post the solution as an answer and mark it as answered.  This will let others know more quickly that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by reordering statements and slightly rewriting the code in the main loop. No more assigning null to the variable. I suspect it was caused by compiler's statement reordering or preemption. Here is what it looks like now causing no more troubles:

```
string url;
if (CollectedLinks.TryTake(out url))
{
  var queued = false;
  while (!queued)
  {
    // Loops thru the array looking for empty slot (null)
    for (byte i = 0; i < TaskArray.Length; i++)
    {
      if (TaskArray[i] == null)
      {
        TaskArray[i] = new Task(FindLinks, url, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
        TaskArray[i].Start(TaskScheduler.Current);
        queued = true; break;
      }
    }

    if (!queued)
    {
      // Loop and clean the array
      for (var i = 0; i < TaskArray.Length; i++)
      {
        if (TaskArray[i] == null)
          continue;
        if (TaskArray[i].Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion || TaskArray[i].Status == TaskStatus.Canceled || TaskArray[i].Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
        {
          TaskArray[i].Wait(0);
          TaskArray[i] = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```